# Multiple Models for one login with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it possible to configure Devise to accept logins for multiple models (either User or Admin) from the same form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do STI with User and Admin (aka `Admin < User`) that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks man, you are correct for that case, we are using 3 different tables for users (for performance and auditing reasons). So it doesn't apply to my problem. Going to be using Authlogic as it's a little more transparent about things and easier to wiggle into a fit for our problem. Thanks!